# Wordpress query_posts posts_per_page not working

Tags: wordpress

Can't figure out why this is not limiting the posts_per_page.  It is displaying a very long list of posts, but I only want to show 4

```
query_posts('posts_per_page=4&post_type=page&pagename=media');

if(have_posts() ) :
while(have_posts()) : the_post();
```

Comment: That should work... Do you make any other loops on the same page? Try calling wp_reset_query(); before the above, to make sure everything is reset.

Comment: You can try using the `posts_limit` filter: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7577213/posts-per-page-not-working-for-new-wp-query/7577261#7577261

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try  wp_reset_query(); before your code.

```
// Reset Query
wp_reset_query();
query_posts('posts_per_page=4&post_type=page&pagename=media');

if(have_posts() ) :
while(have_posts()) : the_post();
```

Answer (score 2):

You are resetting the query each time. You need to include the existing query string, otherwise when you paginate the pagination information will be lost.

Try this instead.

```
global $query_string;
query_posts( $query_string . '&post_type=page&pagename=media' );
```

Also to note, if you are specifing a specific page with pagename=media then how can than paginate, it should only return one page?!

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem on a wordpress site and I tried all the ways to find that site was using Posts per category plugin which was overriding the posts_per_page argument.