# posts_per_page does not function

Tags: php, wordpress, post

Everything works in my code beside posts_per_page (the number of posts it will display). Here is part of my Wordpress code:

```
<?php 
$category = get_the_category();
$current_category = $category[0]->term_id;
$qarr = array(
    'posts_per_page' => $posts_number,
    'cat' => $current_category,
    'tag' => 'pinned', // tag filtered
    'post__not_in' => array(get_the_ID())
);
$q = new WP_Query($qarr);
if($q->have_posts()) : while ($q->have_posts()) : $q->the_post();
?>
```

**Why does it not work?** I have read the documentation and do not understand what the issue is.

Here is the full code if you want to view and test it, just set a number for $posts_number: http://pastebin.com/uNsynNiM

Comment: The default value for posts_per_page is 5. If you were to remove the posts_per_page parameter entirely, do you get 5 posts returned by the query? If not, then there are not enough posts to meet the posts_per_page criteria. Try setting it to a LOW number (like 2). Do you get 2 posts? Do you get more than 2? Do you have at LEAST 2 posts that meet the query criteria?

Comment: @maiorano84 I did set posts_per_page to 1 and it returned more than one - which means that it is not working, correct? Feel free to view the full code that I linked, it is a short script that you can test easily.

Comment: I've also noticed that you've changed the queried tag from 'featured' to 'pinned' in this version. Do you have more than one Post with a tag of 'pinned'?

Comment: Testing on my end, I have 3 posts with a tag of 'pinned' and a posts_per_page setting for 2. 2 posts are returned by the query.

Comment: Also, I just tested changing posts_per_page to **showposts** and it worked perfectly. However, I am resisting on using showposts as it was deprecated. Any ideas what the problem is with posts_per_page?

Comment: What version of Wordpress are you running?

Comment: Yes it was 'pinned' that I ended up using and I have 3 posts there. As I mentioned, I set $posts_number to 1 and changed it to showposts and it displayed 1 post. Then I changed it back and it displays them all again. How can this function for you? It makes no sense why it would work for you and not me...?

Comment: I am using version 3.4.1 - I have not upgraded to v3.4.2 yet.

Comment: Most important question: have you switched all of the query_posts calls in your theme to WP_Query?

Comment: I might be on to something, when you ran your test, did you use the **cat** in the query? I found this post that claims there is an issue when using posts_per_page and category: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/issue-with-posts_per_page-amp-category-combination

Comment: I changed two of them yes, the third returned an error when changing so I have kept that one as it is. That one is not executed on this page that I am testing on regardless. Also I found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7614345/wordpress-query-posts-posts-per-page-not-working

Comment: In my example, I was using only the Uncategorized category on the Index view. I'll see if there's a difference on a category archive using a generated category.

Comment: posts_per_page is still working on my end, but I'm guessing it's because of a difference in themes. I'll write up a quick answer as to what's POSSIBLY going on, but it's impossible for me to say for certain. In the meantime, since 'showposts' works, it wouldn't hurt to use it.

Comment: I tried removing the category from the array completely and same problem remains, posts_per_page is not working. I am baffled as how this is working for you using my exact code!

Comment: Okay I look forward to reading this... cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your previous questions, your theme is primarily using query_posts to run any and all Post Queries against your database. Since this alters the main loop, WP_Query and get_posts are also affected by any and all existing calls to query_posts. I'm fairly certain that the WP_Query call in your Widget is being affected by a rogue query_posts call somewhere.

My suggestion, since it would probably take quite a bit of effort to convert your theme from all instances of query_posts to WP_Query, would be to temporarily use 'showposts' since that's what essentially fixes the problem. I would still advise switching all calls to the query_posts function to WP_Query, only because there is a significant increase in performance by doing so, but ultimately, that would require a significant effort on your part to fix a rather small problem.

Personally, would I do it? As an exercise in good practice, I probably would, yes. Would I say it's worth it? It depends on the project. If this is just a personal project, I wouldn't say it's necessary.

Good luck with this, and I hope it all works out.

Comment: To clarify, posts_per_page in WP_Query is probably being overridden by a showposts parameter somewhere in a query_posts call. Since my theme is essentially a blank theme with no query_posts calls, it would be pretty much impossible to replicate the problem you're experiencing.

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer, it does clear up the issue at hand I will do a search to find which places I am using query_posts and not. I have upvoted this answer and will accept it as correct later tonight. I will leave it open if further input will come from other users. Cheers again for the support!